# Not able to do the migrate in Django, facing Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, migrate

I made a completely new project using the django-admin startproject and I also made an app using django-admin startapp and I am able to apply the initial migrations but not able to do the migrate. and I didn't add any code into the project. It's completely a new project.

```
python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying auth.0013_user_following...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\My Drive\Django 4 by example\myshop\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:\My Drive\Django 4 by example\myshop\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 349, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 130, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 108, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 383, in add_field
    if field.many_to_many and field.remote_field.through._meta.auto_created:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I uninstalled all the packages which I installed for the project, uninstalled Django as well, and deleted all the migrations of all the projects but still it's not working.

Comment: Can you share please your changed models?

Comment: Can you show your models.py